# How to find a formula for $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$ in terms of $\cos ^nx, \sin ^nx$ with complex coefficients?

Tags: trigonometry

It can be shown that $\cos nx$ is expressible in the above form for any integer $n$, and $\sin nx$ for any odd $n$ (with some Galois Theory). But what exactly are the formulas?

Comment: Are you thinking of multiple angles formulas? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Answer (score 0):

Why, it's just the [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula):
$$(\cos x + i \sin x)^n = \cos nx + i \sin nx$$
With some fidgeting and $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$, you may completely get rid of $\sin$ in the expression for $\cos nx$ for any integer $n$, or of $\cos$ in the expression for $\sin nx$ for any odd $n$.

Note that this has nothing to do with Galois theory, nor do we have any complex coefficients in the resulting expressions (though some could have been used in the process).

Comment: But $\cos 3x = \cos ^3x - 3\sin ^2x \cos x$. How would I be able to convert this in terms of $\cos ^3x$ and $\sin ^3x$ only ?

Comment: You would **not**.

Comment: Hint you can let$cosx=u$ then sin is $\sqrt{1-u^2}$ thats all in cos now